# Create a TCP Listener in Kotlin

Tags: sockets, tcp, kotlin

I'm currently giving Kotlin a whirl for a project I am working on. This project requires me to open a Socket and listen for TCP Packets on a port, so that I can later parse them. In Java, the following works if the variables referenced are defined, using a buffer reader, a socket and a server socket:

```
while((CurrentLine = ClientBufferReader.readLine()) != null){FullString += CurrentLine}
```

However, in Kotlin, this does not work, as it is not possible to evaluate an assignment. How could I go about retrieving the same result in Kotlin?

Comment: Can you add the rest of the code? It can help me with my own project in Kotlin. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this particular case, you could rewrite this as

```
val FullString = generateSequence { ClientBufferReader.readLine() }.joinToString(separator = "")
```

This works because `generateSequence` evaluates the lambda passed to it until it returns `null` and emits all non-null items. `joinToString` then efficiently creates a concatenated `String` using a `StringBuilder`.

In general of course, the pattern

```
while((x = foo()) != something) { bar() }
```

can be replaced by

```
var x = foo()
while (x != something) {
  bar()
  x = foo()
}
```

though obviously this is more verbose.

One more note: Your variable names should not start with a capital letter. [See style guide for more info.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#naming-style)